# Utilizar mismo input con el mismo evento pero con diferentes rutas (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

es posible utilizar un mismo evento con una ruta ajax diferente? resulta que tengo una funcion .change que me carga un dato desde un select, pero necesito usar el mismo select con una ruta diferente (diferente ruta y diferente resultado), es posible hacer esto?

En primer lugar la funcion que tengo funcionando:

```
 //Asigna Nombre del responsable Destino
$('#bodega_origen').on('change', function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ url('/bodResp') }}"+`/${id}`,
        method:"get",
        dataType: "json",
            success: function (jdata) {
                var jsonData=jdata
                console.log(jsonData)
                //alert(jsonData.data);
                $('#responsable_origen').val(jsonData.data);
            }
    });
});
```

Y la que necesito tambien incluir:

```
 var bodega_id = $(this).val();
                $('#bodega_id').val('');
                //console.log(empresa_id)
                $('#bodega_id').val(bodega_id);
                $.ajax({
                        url:"{{ url('/bod') }}"+`/${bodega_id}`,
                        method:"get",
                        //data:{select:select, value:value, dependent:dependent},
                        success:function(result)
                        {
                            //console.log(result.data)
                           var opciones = '';
                           var opciones = '<option value="" disabled="disabled">--Seleccione Material a Asignar--</option>';
                           result.data.forEach(element => {

                               opciones += `<option value="${element.id}">${element.detalle}</option>`;
                           });
                           $("#materiales").html(opciones)
                           //$("#servicio_id").append(opciones);
                        }
                    })

                    $("#materiales").on('change',function(){
                    var material_id = $("#materiales").val();
                    $('#material_id').val(detalle);
                    });


}
```

Ambas se deben ejecutar en el evento CHANGE del mismo select

Comment: Añade el código que tienes hasta ahora para poder responder a tu pregunta

Comment: ok, añadido los codigos que tengo

Comment: me muestra este error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Quieres lanzar dos peticiones Ajax desde el evento change del select o quieres dirigir la petición Ajax a diferentes URLs dependiendo del option que haya sido seleccionado?

Comment: No me queda muy claro lo que quieres lograr, pero si quieres que se ejecuten las dos peticiones ajax a partir de un mimso evento simplemente pon las dos peticiones dentro de la misma funcion que dispara el evento, se deve ejecutar una primero y la otra después, de todas formas te recomiendo que enriquezcas más la pregunta.